# Jetpack compose: position elements inside a Box

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `Box` in my app with a bunch of children:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    Text("a")
    Text("b")
}
```

I want the text to appear aligned to the top at 20% distance from the start. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `offset`/`absoluteOffset` modifiers along with `BoxWithConstraints`.

Comment: can you provide an exemple?

Comment: Please provide an example so that we can better understand your answer.

Answer (score 9):

To solve this you need two parts:

2. There're two ways to layout `Box` content: `contentAlignment` will apply alignment for all children, and `Modifier.align`, which can be applied for a specific child.
3. Usually you can use `Modifier.padding` in such cases, but not in case when you need relative size. The easiest way to take part of parent size is using `Modifier.fillMax...`, modifier, in this case `Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.2f)` can be applied to a `Spacer`, placed in a `Row` with your element.

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    Row(
        Modifier
            .align(Alignment.TopStart)
    ) {
        Spacer(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.2f))
        Text("a")
    }
}
```

Comment: The BoxWithConstraints did not work for me, this answer works for the first child in the Column or Row. However, for the other children, the fraction is applied to the size that is left to be filled, not the parent size, which is what I need.

Comment: @PabloValdes I guess you can create a separate row for each item, and they're gonna be displayed on top of each other

Comment: I tried that and it works great, thanks. I still have to get used to the compose way.

Answer (score 3):

follow thewolf's answer

I found this solution.

Let's check this code and the blue box below.

```html
@Composable
fun BoxExample() {
    BoxWithConstraints {
        val boxWithConstraintsScope = this
        val yOffset = 0.2 * boxWithConstraintsScope.maxHeight.value

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(300.dp)
                    .width(300.dp)
                    .background(Color.Red)

            )
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(200.dp)
                    .width(200.dp)
                    .background(Color.Green)
            )
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .offset(y =  yOffset.dp)
                    .height(100.dp)
                    .width(100.dp)
                    .background(Color.Blue)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Look at Blue box]