# How do I center a draggable Box inside a parent Box using offset?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a draggable `Box` inside a parent `Box`. The parent `Box` creates a boundary for dragging. The draggable `Box` starts at the top left of the parent `Box` when the screen renders.

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun DraggableBlock() {
    var parentBoxSize by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .onSizeChanged {
                parentBoxSize = it
            }
    ) {
        val boxSize = 150.dp
        var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
        var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

        Box(
            Modifier
                .offset {
                    IntOffset(
                        offsetX
                            .roundToInt()
                            .coerceIn(0, parentBoxSize.width - boxSize.roundToPx()),
                        offsetY
                            .roundToInt()
                            .coerceIn(0, parentBoxSize.height - boxSize.roundToPx())
                    )
                }
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
                .size(boxSize)
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                        change.consume()
                        offsetX += dragAmount.x
                        offsetY += dragAmount.y
                    }
                }
        )
    }
}
```

I want the draggable `Box` to start out centered inside the parent `Box`. How do I accomplish this?

### Attempts to Solve

#### 1. `contentAlignment` parameter

I tried using the `contentAlignment` parameter but it messes with the dragging functionality—it is hard to drag.

```kotlin
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .onSizeChanged {
                parentBoxSize = it
            },
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
```

#### 2. Parent `Box` `onSizeChanged` modifier

I tried using the `onSizeChanged` modifier from the parent `Box` to get its size. But the initial size is always `0`. So the draggable `Box` still starts at the top left.

```
        val initialXOffset = (parentBoxSize.width.toFloat() / 2) + (boxSize.value / 2)
        val initialYOffset = (parentBoxSize.height.toFloat() / 2) + (boxSize.value / 2)
        var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(initialXOffset) }
        var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(initialYOffset) }
```

#### 3. `BoxWithConstraints` using `maxWidth` and `maxHeight`

I tried changing the parent `Box` to a `BoxWithConstraints` following https://stackoverflow.com/a/71997053/11809808. I used the `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` values from the `BoxWithConstraintsScope`. This worked on the preview and an emulator but not on my Motorola Moto G Power (2021) Android 11, API 30 phone. The draggable `Box` started in the bottom right of the screen.

```kotlin
    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .onSizeChanged {
                parentBoxSize = it
            }
    ) {
        val boxWithConstraintsScope = this
        val boxSize = 150.dp
        val initialXOffset = boxWithConstraintsScope.maxWidth.value - (boxSize.value / 2)
        val initialYOffset = boxWithConstraintsScope.maxHeight.value - (boxSize.value / 2)
        var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(initialXOffset) }
        var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(initialYOffset) }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can apply a `Center` alignment and change the constraint used by the inner `Box`.

Something like:

```
Box(
    Modifier
        .align(Alignment.Center)
        .offset {
            IntOffset(
            x = offsetX.roundToInt()
                .coerceIn(-parentBoxSize.width/2 + boxSize.roundToPx()/2,
                    parentBoxSize.width/2 - boxSize.roundToPx()/2
                ),
            y = offsetY.roundToInt()
                    .coerceIn(-parentBoxSize.height/2 + boxSize.roundToPx()/2,
                            parentBoxSize.height/2 - boxSize.roundToPx()/2)
            )
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting a centered offset once the parent gets measured. In order to do this, given that you already know the size of your child box, you need to convert it to `px`:

```
val boxSize = 150.dp
val boxSizePx = with(LocalDensity.current) { boxSize.toPx() }
```

and then doing this on your parent `Box`:

```
Box(
     modifier = Modifier
         .fillMaxSize()
         .onSizeChanged {
             parentBoxSize = it
             offsetX = (parentBoxSize.width / 2 - boxSizePx / 2)
             offsetY = (parentBoxSize.height / 2 - boxSizePx / 2)
         }
 )
```

You don't need to change anything else.